# Jquery add CSS value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got some code that adds a CSS class to an element when the user scrolls to a certain amount, to make a sticky menu bar (The distance to scroll is dependant on screen resolution so is calculated within the JQuery) - I want to add a CSS value to this class (.header_scroll) so that it changes the height of the element the class is being assigned to on scroll, to the height of another dynamic height element (#nav_wrap)

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

        //Find the height of the header
        var headHeight = $("#header_wrap");
        var headerHeight = headHeight.innerHeight();

        //Find the height of the nav bar
        var menuFindHeight = $("#nav_wrap");
        var menuHeight = menuFindHeight.innerHeight();

        //Add value to class
        $(".header_scroll").css({"height": menuHeight});

        //Add class on scroll
        var nav = $('#header_wrap');

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > ( headerHeight - menuHeight )) {
                nav.addClass("header_scroll");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("header_scroll");
            }
        });

    });`
```

The code to add the class is working fine, however no matter what variations on this I try, the:

```
//Add value to class
        $(".header_scroll").css({"height": menuHeight});
```

Section will just not do anything at all. Looking in inspect element in chrome I'd expect to see

```
height: xxxpx;
```

appear in .header_scroll but it isn't

Comment: show your CSS for the `.header_scroll`, and if put a code snippet would be nice

Comment: Did you add jQuery? Any errors in Console?

Comment: Well I am betting that `header_scroll` does not exist until you scroll so how would it add the height to the element?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".header_scroll").css({"height": 200});
```

This will not add a `height` property to your CSS rule. Instead it will add `style="height: 200px;"` to the `.header_scroll` HTML element(s).

So you would end up with an HTML element like:

```
<div class="header_scroll" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't get the right value of `headerHeight`, that why it doesn't appear in your inspect tools.

Check that you get the correct height of your `#headHeight` element and try this:

```
$(".header_scroll").height(headerHeight);
```